# Static Variables are stored on Data segment then how do they get deleted after the scope is over?

Tags: c++, c, static

> Static Variables are deleted when they go out of scope

If static variables are stored in data segment how the above statement is possible. As far as my knowledge for the above statement to happen it should be stored on Stack Segment.

Comment: Where this quote is from? It is false.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Can you clarify how static member are deleted then ?

Comment: I  am trying to find the reference for this quote

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "deleted". They are not.

Comment: @EugeneSh. For example. I declare a variable static int x ; . Will this variable be deleted after my program execution or will it not be deleted ? If not , how can I free my memory from data segment

Comment: If you mean _destructed_, then static variables (of class types) are destructed by calling their destructors. How, this is a matter of implementation. If you are interested, you can always study the generated assembly.

Comment: yup I meant destruction sorry

Comment: A non-trivial static object will be destructed (i.e., it's destructor will be called) when the program terminates under normal conditions.  My system queues up the destructor using `atexit`.

Answer (score 0):

Static variable are stored  in data segments that is correct but they only get destroyed only after the termination of the program written in programing language they are stored in memory and occupy memory all the time when programe is executing either they are in scope or out of scope .

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the qoutes meant the variable stored in the stack, because they get stored statically and not dynamically

Comment: `static` variables are usually not stored on the stack. Moreover, this is more a comment than an answer.

Comment: static global const @DanielLangr are some of the variable types stored on Data Segement. Am I right ?

Comment: @Anirudh_k This is an implementation issue. C++ has no concept of a data segment.

Comment: What do you mean by implementation issue ? So should a programmer be unaware of these implementations ?@DanielLangr

Comment: @Anirudh_k I mean that C++ does not care about data segments, stacks, heaps, etc. These are all just tools provided by C++ implementations to run programs on particular systems. And yes, mostly you don't need to care about things as data segments. Why do you ask at all? Mostly, all you need to know is that these variables are destructed automatically for you.

Comment: @DanielLangr I believe that knowing the internal implementation details are more helpful in future run

Comment: @Anirudh_k Sure, it might be. But this may be quite a long-term and tedious task. Look at the source code of compilers such as GCC or Clang, study ABIs, etc...

Answer (score 0):

With respect to C:

> **6.2.4 Storage durations of objects**
> ...
> 3 An object whose identifier is declared without the storage-class specifier
> **`_Thread_local`**, and either with external or internal linkage or with the storage-class
> specifier **`static`**, has *static storage duration*. ***Its lifetime is the entire execution of the
> program and its stored value is initialized only once, prior to program startup.***

<sup>*[C 2011 Online Draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)*</sup>

Emphasis added.  C++ is similar:

> **6.6.4.1 Static storage duration [basic.stc.static]**
> 1 All variables which do not have dynamic storage duration, do not have thread storage duration, and are
> not local have *static storage duration*. ***The storage for these entities shall last for the duration of the
> program*** (6.8.3.2, 6.8.3.4).

<sup>*[C++ Working Draft, 2017](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4713.pdf)*</sup>

Memory for objects with `static` storage duration is allocated and initialized when the program is loaded (before `main` is called) and held until the program terminates.  Given the code

```
void foo( void )
{
  static int slocal;
  int local;

  ...
}
```

the memory for `slocal` is allocated (and implicitly initialized to `0`) *once* when the program starts.  That memory stays allocated whether `foo` is currently executing or not, and only one instance exists even if `foo` calls itself recursively.  The *identifier* `slocal` is not visible outside the body of `foo` so we can't access the object through that identifier anywhere else in the code, but the object it designates exists over the lifetime of the program.

The memory for `local`, by contrast, only exists over the lifetime of the function `foo` - an instance of it is allocated at function entry and deallocated at function exit.  If `foo` calls itself recursively, a new instance of `local` is created for each call.

So, no, `static` objects are not deleted when they go out of scope - they are only deleted when the program terminates.

Neither language mandates *where* or *how* objects are stored, only what the behavior should be.  As a practical matter, objects with `auto` storage duration are typically stored on the stack, but they don't *have* to be.  `static` objects may be stored in a data segment, but they don't *have* to be.  It depends on the specific platform and implementation.